# tikz cosine function plot without pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, tikz-calc

I am trying to plot a function with cosine and exp. It can plot the exp part but not the cosine. I have tried `cos`, `\cos`, `cosine`, `\cosine` none work. This code used to work for 3 months ago maybe something got updated meanwhile?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calculus}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,quotes}
\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{47,122,154} 
\definecolor{lblue}{RGB}{83, 201, 250}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->, line width  = 0.3mm] (0, 0) -- (15, 0) node[right] {$t$};
  \draw[->, line width = 0.3mm] (0, -2.5) -- (0, 2.5) node[above] {$ $};


\draw[dblue, line width = 0.5mm, domain=0:15, variable=\x, dblue] plot ({\x}, {2*cos(\x*8)*exp(-\x/4)});

\draw[lblue, line width = 0.5mm, domain=0:15, variable=\x, lblue] plot ({\x}, {2*exp(-\x/4)});

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output I used to get 3 months ago:
[image]

Comment: What does not work for you? I get the following output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouuOl.png

Comment: Hello i added a picture of what it should(and used to) look like

Comment: Perhaps if you put the angle in radians? `2*cos(\x*8 r)*exp(-\x/4)`. And probably you'll need to add `samples` and `smooth` options too.

Comment: It's *impossible* that you got that output with that code. I tried it with all versions of TeX Live from 2012 on and the output is always the same: the angle is considered in degree, unless you specify it to be radians (or convert radians to degrees).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell Ti*k*z to recalculate the value for the `cos()` function into degrees by using `deg()`. You can also say `cos(\x*8 r)` to specify that the argument is in radians.

To make the curve smooth, you can use the options `samples` and `smooth` for the cosine curve.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{47, 122, 154} 
\definecolor{lblue}{RGB}{83, 201, 250}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->, line width=0.3mm] (0, 0) -- (15, 0) node[right] {$t$};
  \draw[->, line width=0.3mm] (0, -2.5) -- (0, 2.5) node[above] {};

  \draw[dblue, line width=0.5mm, domain=0:15, variable=\x, dblue, samples=200, smooth] plot ({\x}, {2*cos(deg(\x*8))*exp(-\x/4)});

  \draw[lblue, line width=0.5mm, domain=0:15, variable=\x, lblue] plot ({\x}, {2*exp(-\x/4)});

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this something new? I am really puzzled how my code used to work but now it does not.

Comment: I am not sure, to be honest. =/

Comment: I just consulted the manual and found that Ti*k*Z (unlike PGFplots) always considers the argument of `cos` etc. to be in degrees.

Comment: @SimonChemnitz-Thomsen The trig functions have always used degrees I believe, certainly back to v 1.18. It's possible to make radians the default with `\tikzset{trig format=rad}` (I think that requires a fairly recent version of TikZ), or in specific cases with the `r` suffix, e.g. `cos(x r)`, but the code in the question, as is, would not have done anything differently a few months back. The last release of pgf/TikZ was in March, actually.

Comment: @JasperHabicht `pgfplots` is no different from TikZ here, both assume degrees  by default.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I probably got this wrong.

Comment: I am just really puzzled by this, thanks for all the help @TorbjørnT. and Japser